# How force spark to move record nonnull fields as _corrupt_record?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, jsonschema, apache-spark-3.0

Consider the code:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}


object JsonAwsSchemaExample extends App{


  val awsCredentials = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials

  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("spark-example")
    .getOrCreate()
  spark.sparkContext
    .hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", awsCredentials.getAWSAccessKeyId)
  spark.sparkContext
    .hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", awsCredentials.getAWSSecretKey)
  spark.sparkContext
    .hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")

  val schema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("_corrupt_record", StringType, true),
    StructField("myErrorField", StringType, false),
    StructField("dataType", StringType, true)
  ))

  spark.read
    .schema(schema)
    .option("enforceSchema", true)
    .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
    .json("s3a://my-bucket/my-table").show(20, false)

}
```

This give me en output like

```
+---------------+------------+------------+
|_corrupt_record|myErrorField|dataType    |
+---------------+------------+------------+
|null           |null        |notification|
|null           |null        |notification|
|null           |null        |notification|
|null           |null        |notification|
|null           |null        |notification|
|null           |null        |notification|
|null           |null        |notification|
|null           |null        |notification|
|null           |null        |notification|
|null           |null        |notification|
+---------------+------------+------------+
```

The `myErrorField` created with `nullable` false parameter but spark do not place any records to `_corrupt_record` column. Is there a way to force this?